# How to implement RLS for SELECT and INSERT seperately

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

```
CREATE POLICY table_policy 
  ON organisation 
  TO role_A 
 USING (id IN (SELECT organisation_id 
               FROM org_user_map_table 
               WHERE user_id = current_setting('app.current_user_id')::uuid));
```

The current RLS policy restricts users ensuring them to view data related to their own organisation.

I am now facing issue while INSERTing a new org into the Database where it throws error saying according to the above policy restriction, since no such organisation_ids are available for the user in the org_user_map_table the operation is not permitted. So, I cannot INSERT the new organisation, let alone access it at a later point.

While a suggestion for adding new roles and policies to perform INSERTS could be added, I have to work with the existing system and I am not sure how to split the policy differently for SELECTS and INSERTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't explicitly specify it, you created the policy `FOR ALL` statements. If you need different conditions for, say, `INSERT` and `SELECT`, create two policies instead:

```
CREATE POLICY table_policy_sel ON organisation
  FOR SELECT
  TO role_A 
 USING (...);

CREATE POLICY table_policy_ins ON organisation
  FOR INSERT
  TO role_A 
 WITH CHECK (...);
```

The condition for the `FOR INSERT` policy can be different from the one `FOR SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you, will test few policy statements and accept the answer in some time.

Comment: Hi, even if I apply just one policy i.e. `FOR SELECT` , I am unable to `INSERT` or  `UPDATE`, If I add another Policy `FOR INSERT` and `FOR UPDATE` with `check(true)` I am able to `INSERT`. But then `UPDATE` is giving me the following error `org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed`

Comment: Well, you can only update rows that you can see, right? Hard to say more without knowing details. But that is probably a different question anyway.

Comment: I am updating the record that I created, so I must be able to do the `UPDATE`. Also, isn't all policy statements by default `PERMISSIVE`. So, why I am required to specify `INSERT` `UPDATE` statements as well? Can you give me any hint so that I can work in that direction.

Comment: Too many too generic questions. Consider reading the documentation. If your `INSERT` policy is different from your `SELECT` policy, you may be able to insert rows that you cannot see later. `PERMISSIVE` or `RESTRICTIVE` apply if you have several policies that apply for a certain action at the same time. No more comments from me, since all this is not about the question at hand.